# ZFS with existing data on 1 HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, raid, zfs

I'm thinking about adding a ZFS Raid-5 to my Ubuntu Server (Home use only). Currently, I have 2 HDD, 1 is 120GB for OS and the other is 4TB for download and torrent.

I will purchase an addition HDD to use ZFS with the existing 4TB HDD.

But my question is how to setup ZFS with the 4TB HDD with existing data on it. I have too much data on it, and it will be a pain to back up about 2TB to another HDD and install ZFS and retransfer it back to ZFS.

Many thanks guys,

Best regards,

Long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to convert in place a non ZFS file system to a ZFS one. You need to backup the former, create the pool and restore your data.

It is also unclear how you want to create a RAIDZ pool with only two 4TB disks. You can only create a mirror or a stripe with two devices.

Comment: Is it possible for me to use RAIDZ with 1 4TB and 2x 2TB? or it has to be exactly the same like 4TB x 3?

Comment: You might create a 2TB partition on the 4TB disk and then create a RAIDZ with it along with the two 2TB disks. That's not optimal but will work. The remaining 2TB on the first disk is usable by another zfs pool or another file system.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to reformat your drive without losing all the data stored on it.

Answer (score 0):

Resize (shrink) partition to have free space, create the ZFS on free space, transfer info from non ZFS to ZFS, then remove old non ZFS partition and grow ZFS.

NO need to copy data to other disk, just have a lot of care when shrink partition and ensure data copied to ZFS is identical (verify the 'copy').